# Open Developer tools is refreshing the page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing with ASP.NET MVC.
With the last Google Chrome update, everytime that I press F12 to open developer tools, the page makes a refresh.
It doesn't mather if it's in localhost or in prod.
But, every other page do not present this issue.